# How to copy Image from Gallery to Intenal Storage in Android

Tags: android

When I take a photo by camera app, I add the photo in gallery.

First I create a image file:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String uuid = Items.get("uuid");

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            uuid, //prefix
            ".jpg",        //suffix
            storageDir     //directory
    );


    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file://" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Then I add it to the gallery.

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

`mCurrentPhotoPath` is the `Uri` to that file.

How can I copy this photo into internal storage.
I want to copy that in that storage for the case that the user deletes the image from gallery or something.

Comment: why are not copying image inside app data/data/ folder which ever user selected? why prefer internal storage.?

Comment: because the camera app has no rights to write directly into internal storage

Comment: No as per my knowledge you can write & store. if you want to save the captured image & protect from deletion by user then I have code for that.

Comment: yes then please post it :)

Comment: see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call camera intent with secure path so image can not able to view in gallery or any photo app but your own app can access the file.

```
public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0x000003; 



   Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
    cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ActivityConstantUtils.CAMERA_REQUEST);

public Uri setImageUri() {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), ActivityConstantUtils.STORED_IMAGE_PATH + "/Images/WOMCamera");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String mCurrentPhotoPath = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        return Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath));
    }
```

In `onActivityResult()` you get the image path where captured image stored & hide from gallery and user.

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        //Image from Camera
        if (requestCode == ActivityConstantUtils.CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


        }
}
```